# Adding custom/existing FrameworkElements to ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, itemscontrol, frameworkelement

When I add an overridden `FrameworkElement` or an existing UI control to an `ItemsControl`, I get the following binding error.

`System.Windows.Data Error: 25 : ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are not valid for item.; Type='Button'
System.Windows.Data Error: 25 : ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are not valid for item.; Type='FrameworkElement'`

How should I be handling mixed `UIElement`/non `UIElement` types to an `ItemsControl`?

```
namespace WpfApplication27
{
    class Data
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
    };

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            m_itemsControl.Items.Add(new Data() { Type = "A" });
            m_itemsControl.Items.Add(new Data() { Type = "B" });
            m_itemsControl.Items.Add(new Data() { Type = "A" });
            m_itemsControl.Items.Add(new Button());
            m_itemsControl.Items.Add(new FrameworkElement());
        }
    }

    public class CustomDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object _item, DependencyObject _container)
        {
            var container = _container as FrameworkElement;
            var data = _item as Data;

            if (data.Type == "A")
            {
                return container.FindResource("ADataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            }
            else if (data.Type == "B")
            {
                return container.FindResource("BDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication27.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication27">

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ADataTemplate">
        <Ellipse Width="5" Height="5" Fill="Red"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="BDataTemplate">
        <Rectangle Width="5" Height="5" Fill="Blue"/>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

    <ItemsControl Name="m_itemsControl">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
            <local:CustomDataTemplateSelector/>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>

        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Comment: You cant add UIElements directly to an ItemsControl, thats not what it is made for. All controls which will appear in an IC must be declared in a Template.

Comment: Other than outputting those errors, it works fine though. Adding templates isn't going to work for what I'm doing as the UiElements are largely dynamically setup.